# How to keep error response bodies with Guzzle

Tags: php, json, error-handling, response, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle to consume from an API.
When an error is thrown in that API, the response looks something like this.

```
Status Code: 500
Content-Type: application/json
-----
{
    error: 'identifier',
    error_messsage: 'foo bar'
}
```

I want that body response ( json encoded ) to be the message in the exception processed by Guzzle.

```
try {
    // Below, a Guzzle request
    $request->send();
}
catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    // returns the error response body we talked about before
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is there a way that allows to do so?

Comment: Did you see this: `getResponse` and the section on HTTP Errors. http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#error-handling I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's @dollery, reading that doc lead me to a solution.

Using the getResponse() method of the exception worked as expected.

```
try {
    // Below, a Guzzle request
    $request->send();
}
catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    // returns the error response body
    $e->getResponse()->json();
}
```